# Extra distance in tabular in LaTeX

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to make a table in LaTeX and I wrote the following program:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c}
\hline ‬ 
& $\gamma_n$ & $\rho_{00}^\infty$  + $\eta_{\infty}$  \\
\hline
& 0.01 & 0.2    \\
\cline{2-3}‬ 
& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-3}‬
\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fig.eps} & 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-3}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-3}‬
& {0.9399} & 0.2  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I want to omit the distance between the second and third row in the second column.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question got migrated to here. Please register to this site in order to comment and accept answers later. Your question is not really clear. What space are you talking about. I do not get a space between second and third row. Maybe include a screenshot and mark the problematic part.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a single table, so my advice is to treat it with nested tables.

I prefer the `booktabs` rules, use the method with vertical rules and `\hline` if you want (but you shouldn't `;-)`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo just for the example

\newcommand{\cincludegraphics}[2][]{% a commodity
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
\cincludegraphics[height=20mm]{fig.eps} &
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.2]}
{$\gamma_n$} & {$\rho_{00}^\infty + \eta_{\infty}$}  \\
\midrule
0.01 & 0.2    \\
0.01 & 0.2  \\
0.01 & 0.2  \\
0.01 & 0.2  \\
0.9399 & 0.2
\end{tabular}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I assume your objective is to make the image file in column 1 span rows 2 through 6 (five rows total) of the table. If this assumption is correct, you may achieve this objective by loading the [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/) package. In the code below, the option `-1.5pt` in square brackets serves to fine-tune the position of the graph so that it's nicely centered in its cell. Depending on the font and font size you use in your document, you may need to fine-tune this adjustment some more.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline ‬ 
& $\gamma_n$ & $\rho_{00}^\infty + \eta_\infty$ \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}[-1.5pt]{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fig.eps}} 
& 0.01 & 0.2   \\ \cline{2-3}‬ 
& 0.01 & 0.2   \\ \cline{2-3}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2   \\ \cline{2-3}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2   \\ \cline{2-3}‬
& 0.9399 & 0.2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```